# use javassist dynamic generate class to do model map, occure java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: javassist

I have two model class, I want to do bean copy from one model class to anthoner model class. I use javassist tech to generate class in memory for model mapping.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/huawei/cbc/model/mapper/codegen/SubscriptionDO_SubscriptionCore_Mapper$2.map(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @268: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to integer
  Current Frame:
    bci: @268
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/huawei/cbc/model/mapper/codegen/SubscriptionDO_SubscriptionCore_Mapper$2', 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/Object', 'com/huawei/cbc/order/subscription/crud/entity/SubscriptionDO', 'com/huawei/cbc/order/subscription/model/SubscriptionCore' }
    stack: { 'com/huawei/cbc/order/subscription/model/SubscriptionCore', 'java/lang/Object' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2bc0 000c 4e2c c000 0e3a 0419 042d b600
    0x0000010: 12b6 0016 1904 2db6 0019 b600 1c19 042d
    0x0000020: b600 20b6 0025 b600 2819 042d b600 2cb6
    0x0000030: 0030 1904 2db6 0033 b600 3619 042d b600
    0x0000040: 39b6 003c 1904 2db6 003f b600 4219 042d
    0x0000050: b600 45b6 0048 1904 2db6 004b b600 4e19
    0x0000060: 042d b600 20b6 0051 b600 5419 042d b600
    0x0000070: 57b6 005a 1904 2db6 005d b600 6019 042d
    0x0000080: b600 63b6 0066 1904 2a12 68b6 006c 2db6
    0x0000090: 0070 b900 7602 00c0 0078 b600 7b19 042d
    0x00000a0: b600 7eb6 0081 1904 2db6 0020 b600 84b6
    0x00000b0: 0087 1904 2db6 008a b600 8d19 042a 128f
    0x00000c0: b600 6c2d b600 92b9 0076 0200 c000 78b6
    0x00000d0: 0095 1904 2db6 0098 b600 9b19 042d b600
    0x00000e0: 9eb6 00a1 1904 2a12 a3b6 006c 2db6 00a6
    0x00000f0: b900 7602 00c0 0078 b600 a919 042a 12ab
    0x0000100: b600 6c2d b600 aeb9 0076 0200 b600 b219
    0x0000110: 042d b600 b5b6 00b8 1904 2a12 bab6 006c
    0x0000120: 2db6 00bd b900 7602 00c0 0078 b600 c019
    0x0000130: 042d b600 c3b6 00c6 1904 2db6 00c9 b600
    0x0000140: cc2c b0                                

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at com.huawei.cbc.model.mapper.factory.JavaassistMapperFactory.dynamicCreateClass(JavaassistMapperFactory.java:48)
    at com.huawei.cbc.model.mapper.factory.JavaassistMapperFactory.createMapper(JavaassistMapperFactory.java:40)
    at com.huawei.cbc.model.mapper.factory.JavaassistMapperFactory.doCreateMapper(JavaassistMapperFactory.java:36)
    at com.huawei.cbc.model.mapper.factory.AbstractMapperFactory.triggerCreateMapper(AbstractMapperFactory.java:52)
    at com.huawei.cbc.model.mapper.factory.AbstractMapperFactory.lambda$createMapper$0(AbstractMapperFactory.java:38)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
```

who know how to decode the ByteCode, help me solve the problem.

Comment: I print the source code which generated by  javassist

Comment: Imagine for a moment that I would ask you the same question, showing you a stack trace but not the source code which caused it. Would you be able to help me? So other than stating the obvious - you are trying to access an object on the stack which you think is an integer, but in reality it is not - I am afraid I cannot help you.